# Creating XML from XML Schema (Drag and Drop)

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an XML schema and want to give the user a Drag and Drop GUI to create their own XML.  Is it possible? Are there any similar software ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's drag and drop, but Altova Authentic is free and gives business users a comfortable XML editor. The editors XML can be bound to (and constrained by) an XML schema.

Download link on CNET:
http://download.cnet.com/Altova-Authentic-Community-Edition/3000-7241_4-75609791.html